# Newtonsoft json access array inside json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, linq-to-json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
   "foo": "bar",
   "1": 0,
   "array": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
   ]
}
```

and I can access "foo" and "1" like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json)
Console.WriteLine((string)o["foo"]) // prints "bar"
Console.WriteLine((int)o["1"]) // prints 0
```

But how can I access the array? I need a string array `string[]`.

Comment: what is stopping you from checking what `o["array"]` returns? (i mean instance of what class) then prolly you can check docs how to iterate such object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JArray jsonArray = (JArray)o["array"];
string[] stringArray = jsonArray.ToObject<string[]>();
```

- The indexer operator of `JObject` returns a `JToken` which needs to be converted to `JArray`
- You can call the `ToObject` on it where you can specify the return type as string array

---

**UPDATE #1**

Well, you don't need to explicitly cast `JToken` to `JArray`, since the `ToObject` is defined on the `JToken`. So the following code would be enough:

```
var stringArray = o["array"].ToObject<string[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a string array from the JArray by using:

```
o["array"].Select(x => x.Value<string>()).ToArray()
```

Comment: Or something like `((JArray)o["Array"]).ToObject<string[]>()`. And for your code, I don't think you need the `Children` part,  as the JToken already has an IEnumerable interface.

Comment: @JHBonarius thanks for the hint, I've removed the `Children` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain access to the array (an instance of [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)) by using:

```
JArray arr = (JArray)o["array"];
```

To iterate over it's elements, you can use the array's [`Children` method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Children.htm).

Complete code example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleAppCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonStr = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"1\": 0, \"array\": [ \"foo\", \"bar\" ] }";

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
            Console.WriteLine((string)o["foo"]); // prints "bar"
            Console.WriteLine((int)o["1"]);      // prints 0
            JArray arr = (JArray)o["array"];
            foreach (var elem in arr.Children())
            {
                Console.WriteLine((string)elem);    // print the array element
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bar
0
foo
bar
```